# How to access parent application HttpOnly Cookie from a child angular 7 app

Tags: angular, cookies, angular7, cookie-httponly, ngx-cookie-service

--Parent c# App hosted on (http://host)

--Child Angular 7 App hosted on (http://host/child)

I need to check for a cookie in parent application. I used 'ngx-cookie-service', it  does not return the HttpOnly cookie. Is there anyway to access the cookie?

Comment: then , what is your question ?

Comment: updated the question